# Ruby on Rails - Access a model sub collection (has_many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have the following model in my project

```
class Attribute < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: true

  has_many :attribute_vals
end
```

and I am trying to do the following in my view

```
<div id="attributes_list">
  <%= @attributes.each do |attr| %>
    <% attr.attribute_vals.each do |val| %>
      - <%= val.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

where @attributes is equals to `Attribute.all`.

But when I load the page, the following error is thrown

> You tried to define an association named attribute on the model AttributeVal, but this will conflict with a method attribute already defined by Active Record. Please choose a different association name.

My models

```
class Attribute < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: true

  has_many :attribute_vals
end
```

.

```
class AttributeVal < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :attribute_id }

  belongs_to :attribute
end
```

Is there any way I can access this sub collection?

Comment: Most probably attribute is a reserved word in Rails, as it's `attributes`. Try renaming your model.

Comment: You probably should have shown `AttributeVal` since the error clearly points to that model. You probably do `belongs_to :attribute`.

Comment: Does Rails allow me to walk through Attribute.attribute_vals.... in erb? If I change the name of my model, will my code really work (I will test)?. Thank you for the quick reply

Comment: Try with what @jvillian pointed out, but I'd recommend you to rename your model, as attribute and attributes are two keywords Rails uses internally.

Comment: I updated my post with the models (Attribute and AttributeVal). An Attribute can have many AttributeVals, but an AttributeVal can only have one Attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ApplicationRecord already using a method named "attribute". I think you should change your model name. But if you want to use like this, you can do like the below:

```
has_one :association_name, :foreign_key: "key_name", class_name: "ModelClass"
```

Probably for your project:

```
class AttributeVal < ApplicationRecord   
  belongs_to :new_association_name, foreign_key: "attribute_val_id", class_name: "Attribute" 
end
```

Source:

http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/read/59-fixing-the-you-tried-to-define-an-association-named-transaction-ruby-on-rails-error

Comment: where is your source ? Is not this one? http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/read/59-fixing-the-you-tried-to-define-an-association-named-transaction-ruby-on-rails-error
have you heard **plagiarized contents are very unethical?**

Comment: Thank you very much, @hamdi! Thank everybody that commented on the post too! This worked like a charm. I was almost thinking that rails had a limitation concerning to this.

Comment: @KickButtowski I always pay attention to such things but I forgot to source when giving quickly answer. I have edited my answer. Thanks for reminding. Augusto, You are welcome. Good works.